Убрать элементы управления с Яндекс карты
По техзаданию нужно встроить на сайт Яндекс карту со скрытыми элементами управления (поиск,верхняя панель, контроллер масштабирования, кнопки такси и навигатора). Через jS получилось убрать только контроллер масштабирования. Как убрать все элементы через JS или CSS?
ymaps.ready(function () {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.769570, 37.634453],
      zoom: 14}
    );
myMap.controls.remove('zoomControl');

  
  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.769589, 37.638453], {}, {
      iconLayout: 'default#image',
      iconImageHref: 'https://api.iconify.design/mdi:map-marker.svg?color=%23FF6E30',
      iconImageSize: [12, 12],
      iconImageOffset: [-16, -32]
  });

  
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
});


В JS API 2.1 вы можете выбрать необходимые элементы управления при создании карты. Используйте controls: [], чтобы убрать все кнопки, кроме «Открыть в Яндекс.Картах», за которую отвечает параметр suppressMapOpenBlock.
Собрал для вас пример в песочнице JSBin.

Спасибо, все сработало, кроме навигатора и такси - у меня на карте они почему-то не скрылись.

Согласно документации, чтобы скрыть элементы управления необходимо в
options конструктора карты передать пустой массив controls:
ymaps.ready(function () {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [55.769570, 37.634453],
      zoom: 14,
      controls: [] # <- вот сюда
  }
);

Тут можете посмотреть список элементов управления, которые можно добавлять или убирать с карты.
